# I'm adding <li> via my submit button and it is pushing past my div. My js function can't fix it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make the page continue to add the list items without breaking past the body element as shown.

[image]

I would like to keep the all the list items within the body and div like the first few. My best idea on how to go through this is by using if statement at the bottom of the JS to rerun autoResizeDiv. Thanks for any help!!

JS

```
$(function() {

var $newItemButton= $('#newItemButton');
var $newItemForm= $('#newItemForm');
var $textInput= $('input:text');

$newItemButton.show();
$newItemForm.hide();

$('#showForm').on('click', function() {
    $newItemButton.hide();
    $newItemForm.show();
});

$newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this prevents the form from submitting which you need
    var newText=$('input:text').val();
    $('li:last').after('<li>'+ newText + '</li>');
    $newItemForm.hide();
    $newItemButton.show();
    $textInput.val('')
    // this empties the text box so you can add a new entry
});

function autoResizeDiv() {
document.getElementById('page').style.height = window.innerHeight +'px';
// document.getElementById('newItemButton').style.height = window.innerHeight +'px';
}
window.onresize = autoResizeDiv;
autoResizeDiv();
if(document.getElementById('addButton').clicked == true) {
    autoResizeDiv();
}
})
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:700px) {

    body {
        background: #111;
        background-size: 780px;
        font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        display: block;
        height:100%;
    }

    h1, h2, p {
        text-align: center;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 50px;
    /*  display: inline-block; */
    /*  margin: 4% 0 0% 165px;*/
        padding: 10% 45% 0 44%;
    /*  vertical-align: middle;*/
    /*  position: absolute;*/

    }

    h1 {
        margin: -1% 0 0 0;
        font-size: .8rem;
        letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    }

    h2 {
        min-width: 70%;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 5% 0 4% 0%;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }

    div {
            margin: auto;
        background: #222;
        width: 360px;
    }

    #page {
    /*  padding: auto;*/
    /*  display: inline-block;*/
        height: 465px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 5%;
    }

    li:nth-child(-n+3) {
        background-color: #B80000;
    }

    li:nth-child(n+4) {
        background-color: coral;
    }

    li {
        margin: .3% -5.2% .3% -5.2%;
        padding: 12px 0 1px 16px;
        height: 35px;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    /*  width: 100%;*/
        /*text-align: 30% 0 30% 30%*/
    }

    p {
        color: #111;
        background: #FFF;
        border-radius: 1.5% / 10%;
        font-size: .85rem;
        margin: 0% 10%;
    }

    #newItemButton {
        position: absolute;
        background: #222;

    }

    #newItemForm {
        display: -webkit-flex;
            -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            background: #222;

        z-index: 10; position:relative

    }
    #itemDescription {
        margin: 3.8px 10px 0 0;
        width: 68%;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 2.5% / 18%;
    /*  padding: 10px 0 0 0;*/
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-align: left;
        text-indent: 10px;
    }


    #addButton, #showForm {
        background: #B80000;
        border: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: white;
        letter-spacing: .9px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #addButton {
        border-radius: 8% / 20%;
        padding: 10px 22px;
        margin: 3px 0px 0 0;
    }

    #showForm {
        border-radius: 3% / 11%;
        padding: 10px 22px;
        margin: 3px 17px 0 0;
        float: right;
    }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
      <script src="myscript.js"></script>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300|Yanone+Kaffeesatz'                
 rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      <head>
        <title> JavaScript Foundations: Variables</title>
        <style>
          html {
            background: #FAFAFA;
            font-family: sans-serif;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body id="body"> 
        <div id="page">
        <img src="lion.png" alt="there's supposed to be a lion">
          <h1 id="header">LISTKING</h1>
          <h2>Buy Groceries</h2>
                      <p>"Lions are awesome, fun to play with, and have to pee a lot"
                -J.K. Growling</p>
          <ul>
            <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
            <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
            <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
            <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
          </ul>
          <div id="newItemButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">new item</button></div>
          <form id="newItemForm">
            <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add description..." />
            <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="add" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No wonder, if you set fixed height to your div.

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is where you've set height in #page in your css. You will want to set an overflow: scroll; or remove the height.

Comment: can set overflow to auto and div will have scrollbar when needed

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at your CSS and adjust the #page div to have overflow, or remove the height entirely.

```
    #page {
    /*  padding: auto;*/
    /*  display: inline-block;*/
        height: 465px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: if use `overflow:auto` won't see scrollbar if it's not needed

Comment: Thank you very much. I am pretty new to coding and I had only every glimpsed overflow. That was very, very helpful. Also a big issue was that I had #newItemButton with an absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your body height:100% to min-height: 100%;
making ul overflow-y:scroll also solves the problem, but a scroll bar may disrupt your look and feel

Comment: Thank you! I switched them to min-height as well.